# Symbolic math package for n-dimensional calculus

Tags: symbolic-computation

Is there a math package that can solve ODEs with $n$ derivatives with $n$ undefined and on $n$-dimensional vectors?

I tried defining $n$-dimensional vectors in Matlab and Maple and had no luck.

Comment: Do you have the symbolic tool box in `MATLAB`. Did you try `A=sym('A',[10,1])` for example?

Comment: That would be 10 dimensional. I want any general n-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Oh.. then yes I agree that there is big hole in symbolic math packages defining `X:Vector` without specifying how many elements. Have you tried `MuPad` interface within `MATLAB` I think you can specify non scalars there.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm not hopeful about MuPad since thats what runs Matlab's sym toolbox.